# Computing Laplacian of $ (Bx)\cdot x$

Tags: laplacian

Could you help me and tell me how I should find the $\Delta((Bx) \cdot x)$ if $B \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ ?

All I can think of is writing
$\Delta((Bx) \cdot x)= \operatorname{div}(D(Bx \cdot x))$.
The final answer is $2\operatorname{trace}(B)$,
but I have no idea how I should get to trace of $B$.
Please help me what way I should use.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a dot product?  If so, try `$\cdot$`.

Comment: Where does $A$ come from?  Use an orthonormal eigenbasis of $\frac12(B+B^T)$ to calculate the Laplacian.

Answer (score 1):

In standard Euclidean coordinates, the Laplacian is the trace of the Hessian:
$$\Delta f = \operatorname{tr}(Hf) = \sum_i \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}.$$

Now:

1. Compute the Hessian of $f(x) = Bx \cdot x.$ Show that the Jacobian is $x^T(B+B^T)$ and the Hessian is $B+B^T$.
2. Use the properties of trace (in particular, linearity and invariance under transpose) to get the formula $\Delta f = 2\operatorname{tr}(B)$.

Comment: Thank you.  I found : $ \Delta x(x)= trace( D^2( u(x))$  Can't this be helpful? How can $D^2 Bx \cdot x$ be computed here?